# testing parse push notifications on an actual android device different from testing on an emulator?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Am trying to test parse push notifications on an actual android device. Upon sending a push from the parse dashboard, i see that they is 1 recipient, but i don't receive a notification on the actual device. My android studio virtual emulator is not running. I suspect that android studio is being recognized as an installation without running the virtual emulator? Is this possible. Does parse recognise installations on actual devices before uploading to the play store?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case the solution was extremely simple: I didn't check package name after copy/paste permissions from documentation. After I fixed it push notifications began to come.

```
<permission
    android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Comment: i fixed it. Apparently my device/app pairing on said actual had not been registered due to background data being off